# Windows Version of ZFS

Tags: windows, zfs, data-integrity, refs, disk-protection

From what I've read about ZFS is that it allows and protects against FileROT. Which is why I commonly use this for all my FreeNAS Machines.

Is there an option like that but for the Windows side of things?

I've not had a chance to look in to ReFS but is this Microsoft's new file system?

Comment: Windows cannot be installed on ZFS if thats what your asking.  More recent revisions of NTFS has a great deal of protection against file rot.

Answer (score 3):

There is no port of ZFS to Windows that I am aware of. There are a few projects mentioned on the net but I have yet to find a live one.

Windows introduced its Resilient File System ReFS, a storage pooling system which offers integrity checking and correction for metadata and optionally also data on the disks. As far as I know, this option was introduced in Windows 2012 R2 but I haven't used it yet - the paint's still a bit too wet for my taste. ;-)

Comment: FYI Serious performance issues have been reported with ReFS on Stripped arrays. Reports of good performance using mirrored arrays.

Comment: I use ZFS for Linux but you might consider [SnapRAID](http://www.snapraid.it/download) which supports Windows, OSX and Linux

Answer (score 1):

There's an OpenZFS port for Windows at https://github.com/openzfsonwindows/openzfs that's actively developed. There was also an old port at https://github.com/openzfsonwindows/ZFSin

But for protection against file rot there's also [Btrfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Btrfs) where [there's also a Windows port for it](https://github.com/maharmstone/btrfs). Its features are almost similar to ZFS. Fun fact: there's even a [boot loader allowing Windows to boot from Btrfs](https://github.com/maharmstone/quibble)

> I've not had a chance to look in to ReFS but is this Microsoft's new file system?

Yes, [ReFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReFS) is also a file system that allows data degradation prevention, with the notable feature set comparable to ZFS and Btrfs